# What is the difference LocationListener LocationCallback?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-location-services

I have been looking at and playing with the [`FusedLocationProviderApi`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi). That class contains these two methods:

```
PendingResult<Status> requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient client, LocationRequest request, LocationCallback callback, Looper looper)

PendingResult<Status> requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient client, LocationRequest request, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)
```

They have very similar signatures and descriptions with the only difference being that one uses [`LocationCallback`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationCallback) and the other uses [`LocationListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener).

The abstract class `LocationCallback` defines two methods:

```
void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability)

void onLocationResult(LocationResult result)
```

and the interface `LocationListener` defines just one method

```
abstract void onLocationChanged(Location location)
```

Disregarding the additional method in `LocationCallback`, what is the difference between these two? Is there some conceptual difference or special use case that makes one preferable over the other? What is the rationale in duplicating the functionality?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll note that `onLocationResult()` returns a [LocationResult](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationResult) - this makes it a lot easier to deal with receiving multiple locations simultaneously - a case you'll run into quite often if you're properly batching location requests by setting [setMaxWaitTime()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setMaxWaitTime(long)).

If you opt to use the older `LocationListener`, you'll receive multiple callbacks to `onLocationChanged()` in a row when batching.

Comment: Hmm. This batching looks interesting. If I get this right I can make a LocationRequest with interval of 10 sec and set MaxWaitTime to 100 seconds and then get all 10 (or more or less) locations in one LocationResult. Could be useful. Upvoted.

Comment: Yep! And on many modern phones, the batching is done directly on the GPS chip, meaning the main CPU doesn't need to wake up at all between batches, leading to some pretty impressive battery improvements.

Comment: I do love short answers that tell me exactly what I needed to know!

Comment: I am using locationcallback and i want to get location updates every single second and for that i have added interval of 1 sec in locationrequest object as `locationRequest = new LocationRequest()
                    .setInterval(1000)
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                    .setFastestInterval(1000);` but still i am getting location update every 10 sec. Can you please explain me why it happens? @ianhanniballake

Comment: @JaydipKalkani - the `setInterval` docs specifically say "This interval is inexact. You may not receive updates at all (if no location sources are available), or you may receive them slower than requested"

Comment: Don't you think it should return location at least every 5 sec if i have setted interval of 11 sec? @ianhanniballake

Comment: and if you want to see my whole code how i am requesting updates then you can see my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115524/should-i-need-to-unregister-locationcallback-for-fusedlocationproviderclient) question. @ianhanniballake